24.04 - tracker-miner-fs-3 eating up all my inotify watches
I recently started getting warnings that I'm running out of inotify watches and that I should increase the number, even with just a couple programs open. Traditionally I had only seen this warning when opening huge projects in a software development IDE, so it really surprised me to see it. I found this little script shared in this post to find the culprit, and fingers are pointing at /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 with 95915 watches open.
I have enough RAM to increase the number of watches, and I can understand why an indexing service would want to keep so many files watched, but just want to check this is expected and not a symptom of a bigger problem in my system, since I never saw this before with hard drives that had orders of magnitude more files than the one where I'm seeing the issue.
Thanks!

You could investigate what Tracker's is indexing with gsettings list-recursively org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files but you could also simply increase the inotify watch limit temporarily and see if that fix your problem.
You can see your current limit with cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
to increase it temporaly do something like sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
and to do it permanently
echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p

